# How do I set a specific GMT end time for the classyCountdown.js plugin?

Tags: jquery, countdown

RE: http://www.class.pm/files/jquery/classycountdown/

This simple jquery countdown plugin presents exactly how I want it to, but the trigger code at the moment only sets a target end time relative to the page load.

```
$('.countdown').ClassyCountdown({
    theme: "flat-colors",
    end: $.now() + 10000
});
```

What I want to ultimately do is set the end time relative to a specific GMT/UTC date and time.

Is this possible, and how is it done/coded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to dig a little into [Unix/Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) time.

Both **now** and **end** parameters are used to specify the start and end times respectively in Epoch time. The jQuery function $.now() returns the the present time in **milliseconds**. Divide the returned value by 1000 and the rest is really simple.

Say you want to count down to 9:00 AM , 25th December, 2015. You need to [calculate the Epoch time to the date first](http://www.epochconverter.com/). The Epoch timestamp for this example is 1451034000. This is in seconds, not milliseconds. So the concerned part of your code should look like this:

```
$('#countdown').ClassyCountdown({
                                   now:  $.now()/1000 ,
                                   end:  '1451034000' ,
                                   ...
                                   ...
                                 });
```

Answer (score 4):

Say you want to count down to 9:00 AM , 25th December, 2015:

```
$('.countdown').ClassyCountdown({
    theme: "flat-colors",
    now: $.now() / 1000,
    end: Date.UTC(2015, 11, 25, 9, 0, 0) / 1000
});
```

Be aware, that month count starts with 0.