# Fixed date on classycountdown.js

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to add a fixed date to the classycountdown.js, a countdown timer plugin. Looking at the examples online everyone sets it to XXXXX seconds from .now() which just resets the timer every refreh.

Is there a way to set it to a fixed date?

```
<div id="rounded-countdown">
    <div class="countdown" data-remaining-sec="20000"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a specific GMT end time for the classyCountdown.js plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984489/how-do-i-set-a-specific-gmt-end-time-for-the-classycountdown-js-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

It's a solution. You can refer. Hope to help, my friend :))

For example, you want to count down to 8:00 AM , 14th February, 2019:

```
$('.countdown').ClassyCountdown({
    now: $.now() / 1000,
    end: Date.UTC(2019, 1, 14, 8, 0, 0) / 1000
});
```

You should be aware that month count starts with 0.